# Jquery - Disable field if criteria is met

Tags: jquery, forms, select

I have a form that has 15 rows. Each row has an ID numbered 1 - 15 (row_id) and each row contains a select field and numerous text fields.

What I'm trying to do is if the select option on row_id's 6 or above are set to anything other than 0 then disable row_id 5 and  if the select option on row_id's 11 or above are set to anything other than 0 then disable row_id 10.

Eg:

```
Any select > 0 on rows 6 - 15 will disable row 5
AND 
Any select > 0 on rows 11 -15 will disable row 10
```

So a select of 2 on row 12 would disable both rows 5 & 10

I've created a fiddle showing the table and how the row_ids are set, but I've now idea how to do this.. 
http://jsfiddle.net/v0kvwfje/2/

Any suggestions ?

---

**Edit**: Code from fiddle:

```
 $("select").change(function() {
      id = $(this).attr("row_id");
      val = $(this).val();
 });
```

Comment: what you have tried so far? Show your test and what is not working so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
 $("select").change(function() {
      var disabled = false;
      var selects = $("select");
      for (var i=selects.length - 1; i >= 4; i--) {
          if (i % 5 == 4) $(selects[i]).prop("disabled", disabled);
          disabled |= selects[i].value;
      }
 });
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vj0vbc05/).

This code will iterate through the `SELECT` elements from bottom to top. Whenever it finds a non-zero entry, it will set the *disabled* variable to  `true`; it can never get `false` again during the rest of the loop.

Once the special rows 10 and 5 are encountered (4 and 9 in zero-based numbering), that *disabled* value is used to set the `disabled` property of the corresponding element.

If ever you decide to extend the list with 5 more rows, and want the same principle to apply to enable/disable the 15th `SELECT` element, then the above code will not have to be changed. It will do the job for every fifth `SELECT` element, no matter how long the list is.

Comment: Thanks this works well. Can you explain this though `for (var i=selects.length - 1; i >= 4; i--) {
          if (i % 5 == 4) $(selects[i]).prop("disabled", disabled);` What would I need to do if I wanted this to apply to the 10/20 entries, 9/18 or the 6/12 etc ?

Comment: The key part of that code is `i % 5 == 4`. It means: *i divided by 5 has a remainder of 4*. If you want to apply it to 10/20 entries, you would write `i % 10 == 9`. For 9/18, you would write `i % 9 == 8`. Another way for that last example could be `(i+1)%9==0`. That might be nicer code, because then you only need to change the 9. The zero always stays.

Comment: @JeffVader, did this answer your question?

Comment: Thanks thats very helpful.

Comment: quick follow up. How do I do this for 27 entries if 9 or 18 are set ?  And can I make the select background color change ? I've spent a lot of time trying this and can't get it to work.. Thanks

Comment: For steps of nine: `if  ((i+1)%9==0) ...`. For the background colour change it depends on whether the row should get that background or only the select. For select element background some browsers do not support it (if I remember well), but just try with CSS, or ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 0):

> Any select > 0 on rows 6 - 15 will disable row 5

translate this to code, using the variables you've already set:

- Any = `if`
- Select > 0 = `val > 0`
- row 6-15 = `id >= 6`  (as there are 15 rows, no need to check explicitly)
- disable row 5 `$("[row_id=5]").attr("disabled", true)`

ie:

```
if (val>0 && id>=6) $("[row_id=5]").attr("disabled", true)
if (val>0 && id>=11) $("[row_id=10]").attr("disabled", true)
```

if you wanted eg 6-10 not 6-end, then add that:  `(val>0 and id>=6 && id<=10)`

or the more generic case of disabling everything before the one selected:

```
  for(var i=1;i<id;++i)
      $("[row_id='" + i + "']").attr("disabled", true);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
 $("select").change(function() {

  //new code starts here
  var section1 = false;
  var section2 = false;
  var indx = 0;
  $("table tr").each(function(){
         if(indx>=6 && indx<15){
            if($(this).find('select').val()==0){    
        section1=true;
      }
   }
   if(indx>=11 && indx<15){
            if($(this).find('select').val()==0){
        section2=true;
      }
   }

  if(section1==true){
    $("table tr").eq(5).find("select").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }else{
    $("table tr").eq(5).find("select").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  if(section2==true){
    $("table tr").eq(10).find("select").attr('disabled','disabled');
  }else{
    $("table tr").eq(10).find("select").removeAttr('disabled');
  }
  indx++;
 });
 //new code ends here

  id = $(this).attr("row_id");
  val = $(this).val();
  alert("ID:" + id + " Value:" +val);

 });
```

[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/v0kvwfje/4/)

Comment: You should use a better selector than relying on `.eq(5)` as that stops you being able to adjust the layout.  eg when someone points out that you shouldn't be using tables like this (OPs code) and you change it, then the code stops working - it shouldn't stop working.

Comment: yeah you are right, but I think on the basis of his provided information it was best possible solution, there might be number of best solutions but for that other thing like table layout might be changes or assigning ids/classes to targeted elements etc.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your existing JavaScript/JQuery code with this:

```
$("select").change(function() {
    var fifthFlag = 0,
        tenthFlag = 0,
        fifthSelectElement = "select[row_id='5']",
        tenthSelectElement = "select[row_id='10']";

    $("select").each(function(){
        var id = $(this).attr("row_id"),
            val = $(this).val();

        if(val > 0){
            if(id >= 6 && id <= 10){ fifthFlag = 1;} 
            else if(id >= 11){tenthFlag = 1;}
        } 
    });

    if(tenthFlag == 1 && fifthFlag == 1){
        $(fifthSelectElement).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $(tenthSelectElement).attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else if(tenthFlag == 1 && fifthFlag == 0) {
        $(fifthSelectElement).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $(tenthSelectElement).attr("disabled","disabled");
    } else if (tenthFlag == 0 && fifthFlag == 1){
        $(fifthSelectElement).attr("disabled","disabled");
        $(tenthSelectElement).removeAttr("disabled");
    } else {
        $(fifthSelectElement).removeAttr("disabled");
        $(tenthSelectElement).removeAttr("disabled");
    }
});
```

Comment: This works, but doesn't re enable rows 5 or 10 when one of the other rows is set back to 0..

Comment: To meet your requirement, I have updated my code.. Please try with this new code.. Hope this will help you to fulfill your requirement.